# How to put ticks on all 12 edges of a Graphics3D box?

Tags: graphics3d, ticks

The code below puts ticks and labels on 3 of the 12 edges of a Graphics3D box. How does one put ticks (without labels) on the other 9 edges?

```
einsteinworldline = Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[3], Arrowheads[0.05], 
   Arrow[{{-100, -100, 0}, {0, 0, 200}}], Line[{{-100, -100, 0}, {100, 100, 400}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {-200, 200}, {0, 400}}, Axes -> True, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, t}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Palatino Linotype", FontSize -> 16]]
```

Comment: I don't recall seeing any option to do this natively.  My memory is not great so I'll wait a while to see if someone else knows a trick for this, but if not I think we'll have to draw the frame (box) manually, tick lines and all, using `Line`.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Tech Support says it is not possible to put ticks on the other 9 edges.